# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'

Tags: visual-c++

I've spent many hours on here looking for help on what is apparently a common error but none that I've seen seems to fit my case.

I am migrating a old out sourced program that was written in Visual Studio 6 C++ to Visual Studio 2012 and fortunately for me as I'm not a C++ programmer (just a lowly VB and C# developer). The migration wizard and the internet have been a great help in helping me find and correct code that the wizard can't handle.

In this code block which I believe is doing nothing more than creating a directory

```
int CreateAllDirectories(const char* pszDir)
{
char*   pszLastSlash;
char    cTmp;


if( _access( pszDir, 0 ) != -1 ) {
    // it already exists
    return 0;
}

pszLastSlash = strrchr( pszDir, '\\' );
if ( pszLastSlash ) {
    cTmp = *pszLastSlash;
    *pszLastSlash = '\0';

    // try again with one less dir
    CreateAllDirectories( pszDir ); 

    *pszLastSlash = cTmp;
}

if ( _mkdir( pszDir ) == -1 ) {
    return -1;
}

return 0;
```

}

an error generates when the results of strrchr( pszDir, '\' ) are assigned to the variable pszLastSlash. From the rest of this code it looks like pszLastSlash = strrchr( pszDir, '\' ); is a valid expression.

Is the issue with the double backslash which to me looks like and escape sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe in this line...

```
pszLastSlash = strrchr( pszDir, '\\' );
```

`pszLastSlash` is not constant but `pszDir` is constant. There are two defs for `strrchr()` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/)...

```
const char * strchr ( const char * str, int character );
      char * strchr (       char * str, int character );
```

Because you input a constant char *, it will try to use the def that returns a const char*, but you're assigning it to a non-const char*. I think that is what is generating your error.

Because `pszDir` is const, the pointer returned to you is const because you shouldn't be modifying the area of memory pointed to by `pszDir`.

If you have allocated `pszDir` yourself, and you know it is *safe* to modify, your could relax your const contraint in the function def? I.e.,

```
int CreateAllDirectories(char* pszDir)
```

But, only do this is `pszDir` is a string that you own and can modify :)

I just noticed in the C++ reference page that...

```
In C, this function is only declared as:
    char * strchr ( const char *, int );
```

So, if you previously used C, then that would explain why you see the error now.

Comment: Yes, it is the answer. You could also suggest to change `const char* pszDir` to `char* pszDir`, because it can be changed inside the function. Or make a copy of it.

Comment: So you are recommending that he try to change the `pszDir` parameter on the `CreateAllDirectories()` to get relief?

Comment: @Soon: thanks for comment, updated. I think he should only change the const'ness of pszDir if he knows it is safe to write to though...

Comment: @Jimbo: He's already assuming that, because he IS writing to it.

Comment: @Ben, good point, yes he is. Given the func def is const, that implies he also thought he wouldn't be, so there is some confusion.. I think it is worth double checking although it is most likely the case, as you say, that he can write to it and does want to.

Comment: Thanks all. Jimbos answer made me do a little more reading and testing. I found that by changing the line of code
pszLastSlash = strrchr( pszDir, '\\' );

to

pszLastSlash = (char *) strrchr( pszDir, '\\' );

Essentially adding an additional cast. The compiler stopped complaining and completes a build. Now to test it!

Comment: @GeneBurk: Hi, I think that is not the best approach because you're discarding const. If you can write to pszDir, then you can relax the const constraint on the variable - better. See Ben's answer as well for definition of "const". By saying the function parameter is const, you are making a lock-tight guarantee to the function caller that you won't modify the string they pass in... by discarding the const with your cast, it's like cheating :) And this could have undesired consequences later on (and is misleading if others are using your code).

Answer (score 0):

Since this line

```
*pszLastSlash = '\0';
```

is modifying the buffer passed into your function, you must not promise your caller that you won't modify the buffer.  Therefore

```
int CreateAllDirectories(char* pszDir);
```

is the correct signature

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting new in the middle of

```
pszLastSlash = strrchr( pszDir, '\' );
```

So, it will be

```
:pszLastSlash = new strrchr( pszDir, '\' );
```